# Attempting to read in a vector from a file and print. Want to separate data with a sentinel, sentinel keeps printing to screen

Tags: c++

I am writing a program to read in numbers from a file into a vector and print that vector to the screen forward and backwards. I am trying to make it so that the program can process multiple data sets input from one file. I was thinking of using a sentinel to separate the data sets in the input file. Currently when I run the program, it is reading everything in but appears to be printing the sentinel to the screen as part of the data.

The input file is set up with these values 0
2
4
6
8
10
11
9
7
5
3
1
-999
0
1
2
3
4
-999
-3
-2
-1
1
2
3
5
and if formatting doesn't look correct they are each on their own individual line.

I have tried swapping out the for loop containing the data being read in to another while loop, which produced the same result.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <vector>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <cfloat>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
float input = 0; 
vector<int>numbers;
int count = 0;
int nsets;
float sentinel = -999; 

ifstream inputFile;
string filename;

cout << "Please enter the input file name: ";
cin >> filename; //allows user to input filename
cout << endl;
cout << "The input file is " << filename << endl << endl; //prints 
 filename back to user
inputFile.open(filename); //opens file

cout << "How many data sets would you like to process? ";
cin >> nsets;
cout << endl;

while (count != nsets) {

    for (int i = 0; input != sentinel; i++)
    {
        inputFile >> input;
        numbers.push_back(input);

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (int i = numbers.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << numbers[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
    count++; 
}
 }
```

I would like to print the data sets but not have the sentinel read in and print to the screen. The end goal is that three (or how many are in the file, my particular file has three) separate sets of data print forward and in reverse.

Comment: What happens if you make the sentinal an int?

Comment: You `push_back(input)` before you check if it is the sentinel value or not - obviously it is in the vector already

Comment: @UnholySheep When in this case is it checking if it is the sentinel value? Would you have any recommendation for what would fix this scenario?

Comment: It checks at the beginning of each iteration. That's how `for` loops work. Just use an `if` after you get the input to see whether it should be added or not

Comment: @UnholySheep This worked. Silly me for missing this. Thank you for the detailed explanation.